Prove an inequality about symmetric polynomials
$x_i\geq0,\sigma_1=\sum x_i,\sigma_2=\sum x_ix_j,\sigma_3=\sum x_ix_jx_k,...,\sigma_n=x_1x_2...x_n,$.
They are elementary symmetric polynomials about $x_i$,
Prove:$$(\frac{\sigma_n}{C_n^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq(\frac{\sigma_{n-1}}{C_n^{n-1}})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}\leq...\leq(\frac{\sigma_{k}}{C_n^k})^{\frac{1}{k}}\leq...\leq(\frac{\sigma_{1}}{C_n^1})^{\frac{1}{1}}$$
I have proved that it is correct when $n=3$.
I try to generalize it but I don't know whether it is true for all the positive integers. Hope someone can help me!

Is there a way you can make the first line clearer? I really like what I think this question is asking (I find symmetric polynomials fascinating) but cannot be certain what your first line is saying.

That is Maclaurin's inequality .

@ Martin R :Thank you！I find it.
